# How to shutdown a remote computer from a windows service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I'm trying to shutdown a windows computer in my network, from a windows service running on another windows computer.

In the console, I can do that:

```
net use \\ComputerName Password /u:User
shutdown /s /t 0 /m \\ComputerName
```

But when I try to do it from my windows service:

```
Process.Start("net", "use \\ComputerName Password /u:User");
Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0 /m \\ComputerName");
```

Nothing happens.

I know there is a permissions problem because my service is running on LocalSystem account, but I tried to change it to my local user and still not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, you can do this progmatically using the documented WMI [Win32_OperatingSystem/Win32Shutdown method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The linked article also as has links to examples on how to use WMI from C++

Comment: When I try with that method I get an access denied exception

Comment: I put the machine name before the username (machineName\UserName) on `Username` Option and now there is no exception, stops on `Scope.Connect();` and nothing happens

Comment: well... I put the call to my `remoteShutdown` function at `onStart` of my service and works, but not if I call the function from insde my code

Comment: Now it works. A bug when i was calling my `remoteShutdown` function did my service stops. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Process.Start` you are calling each command in a separate session.  You need instead to launch a single process for your command prompt, and invoke both commands through the same session. `cmd /?` is your friend.

```
cmd /c [commands]
```

... one can chain commands with `&` or `;`.

Comment: Thanks Dan Puzey. I'm searching how to do that, but I can't find anything. Maybe you can explain me how.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, I tried with 'Process.Start("cmd", "/c net use \\IP password /u:User & shutdown /s /t 0 /m \\IP");' in a console application and works fine, but in my windows service nothing happens...

Comment: @IngenieríaTecnovaAtnova: I edited some more information into the answer. But I have no idea why it fails in your particular case. For all practical purposes it should work ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L: edits to other people's answers should be minor edits for clarity or formatting.  If you want to post reams of content that changes the answer I gave, can I politely suggest that you post it as your own answer?

Comment: The cmd method sometimes works, sometimes not... Is very frustrating